# Org mode. Table not sort by date

Tags: org-mode

windows 10, emacs 26.1
I have table in org file and I want to sort table by column `Date`

Here table:

```
|        Number |       Date |
|---------------+------------|
| 1535749200000 | 31.08.2018 |
| 1535835600000 | 01.09.2018 |
| 1590094800000 | 21.05.2020 |
| 1536019200000 | 04.09.2018 |
| 1536883200000 | 14.09.2018 |
```

Note: Date is in format "dd.MM.yyyy"

Here my steps:

```
M-x org-sort
```

[image]
[image]

Then press `t`

Here result. 
[image]

As you can see it's not sort. And I get message:

```
You can run the command ‘org-sort’ with C-c ^
```

Comment: you make it difficult to reproduce by attaching images and not text that could be pasted for testing. first thing I see is that your dates are not datestamps..

Comment: @manandearth I update my post. Add table as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to have a third column, you can also define a function for sorting DD.MM.YYYY formated dates like so:

```
(defun compare-german-date (str)
  "Convert DD.MM.YYYY to sortable YYYYMMDD."
 ( setq stringslist  (delete "" (split-string str "\\.")))
 (string-to-number (concat (nth 2 stringslist) (nth 1 stringslist) (nth 0 stringslist)) )
)
```

then you can use org-sort with "f" for function and provide `compare-german-date` there (2nd function can stay default).

This doesn't change your table entries, it provides a key for sort. So your table will not have YYYYMMDD, but 'll stay DD.MM.YYYY.

Beware using it for other columns than just `| DD.MM.YYYY |`…

You might consider using manandearth's answer though, because having timestamps could be very handy integrating data with org. Or maybe – if you don't like timestamp – consider using ISO-formated dates (as you could easyly sort them alphabetical).

Comment: sorry for lot's of edits - made some c&p mistakes ^^ should work now…

Answer (score 4):

`org-sort` by date will work with timestamps.
For example:

```
| number | date             |                                                                                                                 
|--------+------------------|                                                                                                                 
|    781 | <2018-12-07 Fri> |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|    129 | <2018-12-03 Mon> |                                                                                                                 
|    321 | <2018-11-23 Fri> | 
|    123 | <2018-12-04 Tue> |
```

With the caret in the date column type: <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>t</kbd> for sorting by time.

Wil result in:

```
| number | date             |                                                                                                                 
|--------+------------------|                                                                                                                 
|    781 | <2018-12-07 Fri> |                                                                                                                 
|    123 | <2018-12-04 Tue> |                                                                                                                 
|    129 | <2018-12-03 Mon> |                                                                                                                 
|    321 | <2018-11-23 Fri> |
```

**EDIT**

In your case you will need to reformat those strings using regular expressions.

You can write a function such as:

```
(defun format-date-column (d)                                                                                                                     
   (concat "<" (replace-regexp-in-string   "[.]" "-" d) ">"))
```

and then apply it in the table formula field.
In the following example I made a third column and the function parses between columns:

```
#+tblfm: $3 = '(format-date-column $2)
```

Turning this table:

```
|        Number |       Date | timestamps |                                                                                                 
|---------------+------------+------------|                                                                                                 
| 1535749200000 | 31.08.2018 |            |                                                                                                 
| 1535835600000 | 01.09.2018 |            |                                                                                                 
| 1590094800000 | 21.05.2020 |            |                                                                                                 
| 1536019200000 | 04.09.2018 |            |                                                                                                 
| 1536883200000 | 14.09.2018 |            |
```

To:

```
|        Number |       Date | datestamps   |                                                                                                 
|---------------+------------+--------------|                                                                                                 
| 1535749200000 | 31.08.2018 | <31-08-2018> |                                                                                                 
| 1535835600000 | 01.09.2018 | <01-09-2018> |                                                                                                    
| 1590094800000 | 21.05.2020 | <21-05-2020> |                                                                                                 
| 1536019200000 | 04.09.2018 | <04-09-2018> |                                                                                                 
| 1536883200000 | 14.09.2018 | <14-09-2018> |
```

Which can then be sorted as explained above.

Comment: Not work in my case, because date format is dd.MM.yyyy. Org mode sort only if date is in format yyyy-MM-dd. How I can fix this?

Comment: Now included in the edit.